# Does $E[p_X(X)]$ have any significance?

Tags: probability

I always find it very interesting when I find out stuff that looks superficially insignificant, or even silly, turns out to have deep implications in unexpected fields of mathematics. So I wondered what happens when you take the expectation of the pdf/pmf itself. Could there be a reasonable interpretation of this operation or is it just a trivial form of entropy that is more difficult to work with?

EDIT: I just bumped into a case where I needed $\mathbb{E}[P_X(X)]$. In finite blocklength information theory, there is something called the Dependence Testing Bound that guarantees the existence of a coding scheme with probability of error not exceeding $\epsilon$, that for binary linear codes takes the expression

$$\epsilon \leq \mathbb{E}[2^{-(i(X;Y)-k)^+}],$$

where $i(x;y)$ is the information density defined as $i(x;y) := \log \frac{p(y|x)}{p(y)}$.

Most often, what is useful is actually $\mathbb{E}[\frac{1}{p(X)}]$. It's interesting (but maybe obvious to the experts) that this is the MGF of the instantaneous entropy of $X$ evaluated at $t=1$.

Answer (score 1):

If random variable $X$ has a density $p_X(x)$, then
$\mathbb E[p_X(X)] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty p_X(x)^2 \; dx$.  Since $p_X$ can be unbounded, this is not necessarily finite.
 One thing you can say about it, using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, is that if this is finite, then
for any  (Lebesgue) square-integrable function $f$, $\mathbb E[f(X)]$ exists and
$$ |\mathbb E[f(X)]| \le \|f\|_{L_2} \; \left(\mathbb E[p_X(X)]\right)^{1/2}$$

Similarly, if random variable $X$ has a pmf $p_X(x)$, nonzero on the 
countable set $S$ of possible values of $X$,
then $\mathbb E[p_X(X)] = \sum_{x\in S} p_X(x)^2$.  This time the sum is finite, since $p_X(x)^2 \le p_X(x)$ and $\sum_{s\in X} p_X(x) = 1$.  And again, if $f \in \ell_2(S)$, 
$$  |\mathbb E[f(X)]| \le \|f\|_{\ell_2} \; \left(\mathbb E[p_X(X)]\right)^{1/2}$$

Comment: Isn't it necessarily finite? I mean if $p_X(x) < 1$ then $p_X(x)^2 < p_X(x)$ so it should always exist, shouldn't it?

Comment: There is no requirement that a density be less than $1$.  It doesn't even need to be bounded at all.  For example, you could have $p_X(x) = 1/(2 \sqrt{x})$ for $0 < x < 1$, $0$ everywhere else.